# Determining the location of Top Of Stack

Tags: stack

I am trying to create an array based implementation of Stacks. I am a bit confused with where should the `Top Of Stack` (a variable in my implementation) be when,

- The list is empty
- The list is full
- The list is neither empty and not full
  Please help me out.

Thanks.

Comment: Your question doesn't really make sense. The top of stack should always point to/reference the top of the stack. If there is no top (empty stack), then it should point nowhere/be invalid. Without a code sample, it's really hard to know what you are asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends only how you define `TopOfStack`: is it the first unused slot? Or is it the last thing pushed onto the stack.

As soon as you choose one of those two options the rest can be deduced easily.

Comment: I thought that TopOfStack always is the last thing pushed into stack.

Comment: That is an implementation detail that's up to you to decide. The users of your stack implementation will not (and must not) see this.